# swapping via jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have a button that i want a user to click and it turns into a spinner like [this](http://www.assignmentx.com/wp-content/themes/assignment-x/images/spinner.gif) so what i was thinking was to have it like this...

```
<form method="post" id="new_resource" class="new_resource" action="/resources">
  <div class="field">
    <input type="text" size="30" name="resource[url]" id="resource_url">
    <input type="hidden" value="5" name="resource[course_id]" id="resource_course_id">
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <input type="submit" value="Create" name="commit" id="resource_submit">
  </div>
</form>
```

So what i need is if someone clicks on the submit form button with id="resource_submit that i would display a spinner...I was thinking of putting the spinner below this input tag in a span or an image tag but i wasnt sure the best way...

Here is my Jquery so far

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
 $(this).find('#resource_submit').hide();
 e.preventDefault();
});
```

I have multiple forms on the page so thats why i am using this approach but i dont know how to implement the spinner logic

Comment: In addition to what everyone else has answered, since you have multiple forms, you should use a class instead of an ID for the selector. You can't have duplicate IDs in the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're missing here, aside from a hidden image of an animated spinner.

**CSS**

```
.noShow{display:none;}
```

**HTML**

```
<img src="/images/spinner.gif" class="noShow" />
```

**JS**

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
    $(this).find('#resource_submit').hide();
    $(this).find('#spinnerImage').show();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

put this html somewhere in your page:

```
<div id="spinner" style="display: none"><img src="spinner.gif" /></div>
```

then in your form submit function:

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
  $(this).find('#resource_submit').hide();
  $("#resource_url").after("#spinner");
  $("#spinner").show();
  e.preventDefault();
});
```